# Cannot find arduino COM1 port in device manager

Tags: compiler-errors, port, arduino-uno

I was coding a sketch for my arduino uno, but when I tried compiling it, I got the following error:

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM1": The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I looked online for an answer, and it said to change the COM1 port for my arduino in the device manager. However, when I looked in the device manager, I could not find the port.

Comment: Nvm, was using a DCcduino with the arduino software :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ch341g, sometimes your operating system may not detect the serial interface. You need to have proper drivers installed for it to work. After installing the ch341g driver, you can be able to view it on the device manager as well as the Arduino IDE tools. Instructions for mac OSX is [here](http://www.homautomation.org/2015/02/05/how-to-use-arduinos-with-ch340g-ch341g-serialusb-ftdi-chip/). For windows, instructions are [here](http://www.arduined.eu/ch340g-converter-windows-7-driver-download/).

Comment: Do you know how I could manually install it? I opened the setup application and it said to install it by hand.

Comment: which operating system do you have?

Comment: I am currently using Windows 7

Comment: After downloading the zip file, open up the folder CH341SER in that. There you will find a setup.exe file. And in that CH341SER folder, there ll be another folder named DRVSETUP64. In that folder also there is a driversetup.exe file. I am not using windows, but try running the 2 .exe files to install. I hope it will do.

Comment: What board do I put it as in the arduino ide?

Comment: Which board do you have? I mean clone of which board, Uno or Mini or what? If you don't know, just see what's written on the IC chip of the board, like atmega328 or what. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

@TDM 2

Which arduino Board you are using. When you connected Arduino device make ensure the following

1) check in device manager-> port section-> Arduino board has detected or not. If detected port but highlight with yellow color , That means you not installed driver properly

2) Open arduino Ide. Goto tools-> Serial ports-> choose right comport

3)check weather USB to Serial Ic get heatsUp when you added the usb cable.
Chances of damage of IC.

Comment: It turns out that I was using a chinese clone with a ch341g chipset lol.

Comment: Didi you checked the Comport section. Did you followed my procedure and let me know where u gone wrong

Comment: Yes. when I checked the device manager, there was nothing under the ports section, and in the arduino ide, I wasn't able to select a port.

Comment: can u send screen short of device manager . Please connect device connected.